# How make a COUNT in function of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, count

I have a table in PostgreSQL, table1, with 5 columns (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e). col_a is timestamp type and col_b is integer_type. I want to make a function with two parameters that returns count of col_b.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION first_count (year schema.table1.col_a%type, col_b schema.table1.col_b%type)
    RETURNS void AS 
$$

DECLARE
 contador integer; 
 

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(col_b)  INTO contador
                FROM schema.table1
                WHERE schema.table1.col_b = col_b AND EXTRACT(year FROM 
                schema.table1.col_a) = year;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This works but when I try to pass parameters it gives me an error.

My aim with function is get the result like this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(col_b)
FROM schema.table1
WHERE col_b = 2216 AND EXTRACT(year FROM schema.table1.col_a) = 2009;
```

Comment: You need to use `SELECT ... INTO variable` in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for your answer, I tryied to use INTO but I don't get it.

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) covers that in detail.

Comment: `INTO` is spelled out here [INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)  Look at the example function at the bottom of the section(ignore the `STRICT` portion). If that does not make sense, show us in your question what you attempted to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question using INTO. The function work but I don't get the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you extracted from the table column. So :

```
SELECT COUNT(col_b)  
  INTO contador
  FROM schema.table1
 WHERE schema.table1.col_b = first_count.col_b 
   AND EXTRACT(year FROM schema.table1.col_a) = 
       extract(year from year) ;
```

This also shows why *year* is a poor chance for the column,variable, or parameter name. There are 2 considerations for your parameter names. First, it is poor practice using the same name for parameters and table column names. Without proper qualification Postgres will always assume the column name in any SQL statement. So the predicate: `where schema.table1.col_b = col_b` is essentially the same as `where true`. A very common convention to avoid this is prefixing parameters with "p_",  So p_col_a.  Secondly, while Postgres does not consider *year* a reserved word it is a SQL standard reserved word. Not to mention the possible confusion with predicates like

```
extract(year from year)
```

Postgres will keep it straight by context; will you and other developers?

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return anything, that's why you get no result.

You need to change it to `returns bigint`, and you don't need PL/pgSQL for this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION first_count (year int, col_b schema.table1.col_b%type)
    RETURNS bigint --<< here
AS 
$$
  SELECT COUNT(col_b)
  FROM schema.table1
  WHERE schema.table1.col_b = col_b 
   AND EXTRACT(year FROM schema.table1.col_a) = year;
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I get the next error: operator does not exist: double precision = timestamp without time zone

Comment: That is a different question. I assumed the datatypes of your parameters matches the columns.

Comment: @Raq: you probably just need to change the type of the `year` parameter

Comment: Thanks, the year parameter is timestamp, how can I change it?